# Insert icon into mydatabase

Tags: php, mysqli

How can I insert a icon in my database from php through object oriented method ?

table name

ser_icon is my database column name

Answer (score -1):

You must mention what have you done so far to fix the issue. Any solution/codes you can mention. But here is a small help:

Its not recommended to store any kind of image into the database. Rather store it in directories and save the paths into the db for manipulation. However, if you still want to save any image in the db, you need a field with type **'BLOB**', which is used to save images/icons in the database.

You can do something like this:

```
// Image submitted by form. Open it for reading (mode "r")
$fp = fopen($_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name'], "r");


if ($fp) {
     $content = fread($fp, $_FILES['file_name']['size']);
     fclose($fp);

     // Add slashes to the content so that it will escape special characters.
     // As pointed out, mysql_real_escape_string can be used here as well. Your choice.      
     $content = addslashes($content);

     // Insert into the table "your_table_name" for column "ser_icon" with our binary string of data ("content")     
     mysql_query("Insert into your_table_name (ser_icon) Values('$content')");
}
```